# how can i draw a shape with a button using kineticjs?

Tags: button, draw, kineticjs

I'm beginning to use canvas and kineticjs. I tried to draw a rect when clicking the button "add text", in the function I declare a `var Text`, add the `var Text` in the layer and then add the layer to the stage, can anybody help me?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 578,
      height: 200
    });
    var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

document.getElementById("Draw_text").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var Text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        text: "hi",
        draggable: "true"
    });

    shapesLayer.add(Text);
    stage.add(shapesLayer);
}, false);

<body onmousedown="return false;">
<div id="container"></div>
  <div id="buttons">
      <button id="Draw_text">
      add text
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your strategy.
In order to do this you can use a very simple trick. First draw any shape that you need and then use hide() and show() function. By using this method u can get what you are looking for.
* Do Not declare your text inside the onclick function.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 578,
      height: 200
    });

    var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var Text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        text: "hi",
        draggable: "true"
    });

   document.getElementById("Draw_text").addEventListener("click", function () {
   Text.show();
   shapesLayer.draw();
   }, false);

   document.getElementById("Delete_text").addEventListener("click", function () {
   Text.hide();
   shapesLayer.draw();
   }, false);

   shapesLayer.add(Text);
   stage.add(shapesLayer);
   };
```